# Certificate Error on FTP Upload using basic-ftp

Tags: javascript, ftp

I am trying to upload a file using [basic-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp) and this simple script:

```
import * as ftp from "basic-ftp";
import 'dotenv/config';

doUpload();

async function doUpload() {
    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = false;
    try {
        await client.access({
            host: `${process.env.HOST}`,
            user: `${process.env.USERNAME}`,
            password: `${process.env.PASSWORD}`,
            secure: true,
            secureOptions: {
                host: `${process.env.HOST}`,
            }
        });
        console.log(await client.list())
        await client.ensureDir("/public_html/json/social-finder");
        await client.clearWorkingDir();
        await client.uploadFrom("file1.json", "file1.json");
        await client.uploadFrom("file2.json", "file2.json");
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
    client.close()
}
```

I'm getting the error "Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames", error code `ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID`. I use the same credentials and setup with FileZilla with no issues, including over explicit TLS which is why I have `secure: true` in my access options above.

What does this error mean if I can use this URL to access my server usually without problem via an FTP client? Is there something missing in my setup?